# CloudBerry Backup (Linux) to Amazon Glacier

Tags: linux, backup, amazon-glacier, cloudberry

With the sunset of CrashPlan I'm exploring different options for backup; Cloudberry with Amazon Glacier seems like a good option. I've been able to set up my Windows machine to backup locally and to the Glacier without issues, but can't seem to find any way to add Glacier as a backup destination on the ubuntu machine (LAN backup works fine).

[These are the options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzIpa.png) that appear under cloud storage.

I can use Amazon S3, but this is not the same as Glacier (I need to give the IAM user specific S3 permissions to use this). Tried "S3 Compatible" but it asks me for an Endpoint which I'm not sure what to use.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Another option is to use an S3 lifecycle rule to automatically change your files in S3 to [Glacier storage class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-class-intro.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and thanks for evaluating our product.
For Linux we don't use direct upload to Glacier. 
Please go to **edit | lifecycle policy** and set **archive to Glacier** transition to **0 days**.
In that case, your files will be transferred automatically from S3 to Glacier with no additional costs.

Comment: I know that in the latest version there is a checkbox near the account credentials called "Archive to Glacier"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! @Denis_CBL answered the question, but another tweak is needed before the archive to Glacier will work. My "Lifecycle policy" dialog was blank and there was no way to set the transition to Glacier.

[lifecycle policy dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFC9Z.png)

You need to click on the blank space marked with the yellow bar, then the Amazon S3 backup option will appear, after which you can set Lifecycle policy as described by @Denis_CBL.

Comment: The dialog implies that restore costs can be higher for S3 IA class, which is incorrect. Glacier restore costs can be higher than S3, so anything you expect to download in the foreseeable future should stay on S3.